# How to get the fist digit of a number

Tags: r

I want to get the first digit of a number in the R language (which is the left digit). How can I do that?

```
532648 → 5
874 → 8
3897 → 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `substr`

```
as.integer(substr(v1, 1, 1))
#[1] 5 8 3
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(532648, 874, 3897)
```

Comment: What about negative numbers? This will return NA

Comment: @camille It is not mentioned in the post.  Also, the other answer with `floor(log10(x))` returns NaN

Answer (score 3):

The numbers you’re looking at are decimal, that is, base 10. To get the *magnitude* (i.e. the number of base-10 digits) of such a number, use the `log10` function:

```
x =  c(532648, 874, 3897)
floor(log10(x))
# [1] 5 2 3
```

Now you can use the magnitude to get just the most significant digit:

```
as.integer(x / 10 ^ floor(log10(x)))
# [1] 5 8 3
```

Note that this will fail if the input is `0`, since log(0) is undefined (or −∞).

To proof the code against non-positive (0 or negative) inputs, use the following:

```
most_significant_digit = function (x) {
    magnitude = floor(log10(abs(x)))
    as.integer(x / 10 ^ ifelse(is.infinite(magnitude), 1, magnitude))
}
```